# Kendo treeList with pager widget?

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, widget, kendo-grid, kendo-treelist

Since kendo treeList does not support paging, how can i use the kendo pager widget with treeList?
Here is the example created with treeList and kendo pager: http://dojo.telerik.com/akAwe/13

Thanks.

Comment: Kendo-Treelist dose not support paging. http://www.telerik.com/forums/does-treelist-support-pagination

Comment: @Jayesh Goyani: Please see this example in the link: [link](http://www.telerik.com/forums/does-treelist-support-pagination)   How can i do something similar with the example i created in     http://dojo.telerik.com/akAwe/13   ?

Comment: The example which was given by you its not working.

Comment: I followed the solution given in the link: http://www.telerik.com/forums/does-treelist-support-pagination

Comment: @JayeshGoyani are you still available. i need your help to fix in kendo treeview multi select check box